# Installing QT in Centos - CMake Warning whike installing OpenBR

Tags: c++, qt, centos, qt5, centos6

I am trying to install [OpenBR](http://openbiometrics.org/doxygen/latest/linux_gcc.html) in CentOS. The steps given [here](http://openbiometrics.org/doxygen/latest/linux_gcc.html) is for Ubuntu. Where as I need to install the OpenBR library in Centos. I am using "Centos-6.5" version.

The below is the step OpenBR team has asked to follow to install QT.

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default libqt5svg5-dev qtcreator
```

What should I do to install the same in CentOS.

I followed the steps in this [link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25550) to install QT.

When I give this command am getting the below error (I trimmed the error for easy view). What would be the issue?

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:82 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Concurrent.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Concurrent", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Concurrent"
  with any of the following names:

    Qt5ConcurrentConfig.cmake
    qt5concurrent-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Concurrent" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Concurrent_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Concurrent" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:82 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Core.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Core" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
    qt5core-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Core" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Core_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Core" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:82 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Gui.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Gui" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
    qt5gui-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Gui" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Gui_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Gui"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
  .
  .
  .


CMake Warning at 3rdparty/stasm4.0.0/CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


CMake Warning at 3rdparty/stasm4.0.0/CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Xml.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Xml", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Xml" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5XmlConfig.cmake
    qt5xml-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Xml" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Xml_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Xml"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


CMake Error at 3rdparty/stasm4.0.0/CMakeLists.txt:41 (qt5_use_modules):
  Unknown CMake command "qt5_use_modules".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/raaa/Downloads/openbr/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get pre-built qt 5 packages for CentOS 6 from EPEL. First, install the EPEL repository:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh \
   http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Then use yum to install the qtbase devel module, and any other modules you may want.

```
yum install qt5-qtbase-devel
```